# Modify Windows 10 bash shell to look and behave exactly like Ubuntu bash shell

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I just installed the bash shell on my Windows 10. I'm currently playing around with it. What changes should I make to make it look and behave exactly like Ubuntu's bash shell? Also, what are the major differences I should keep in mind while using it?

Comment: Did you consider installing Ubuntu on a VM? It would be much simpler

Comment: Highly related but no duplicate: [How does the new “Bash on windows 10” really work?](/q/755950/175814) as well as [Bash on Ubuntu on Windows – Frequently Asked Questions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/faq)

Comment: I have Ubuntu dually booted @M.Becerra. Sometimes I use the bash shell in Windows when I am using Windows to access my work computer and do stuff and I don't want to switch to Ubuntu.

Comment: FWIW, the bash shell you get when you install Ubuntu on WSL **IS** the Ubuntu bash shell.

Comment: @RichTurner It is the Ubuntu Bash Shell but a little better with mouse support I think.

Comment: No - when you run Ubuntu on Windows you're running the same /bin/bash as you get on "real" Ubuntu - same binary, etc.

Comment: In WSL, you run the same bash and the same binaries of any other "real" Ubuntu. However, these binaries use a different linux kernel. WSL use a user-space kernel that runs just like any other Windows application. -- There are some differences because the WSL kernel does not support all the Linux options. For instance, you cannot use SYSV IPC. You may check the [release notes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/release_notes) in MSDN and the [Issues](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues) in Github